# Angular CDK Overlay Limit Position Scope

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

While using the Angular CDK and its Overlay, I wondered if there's a way to use the position-builder with a scope limited to a container. So that its global positioning context is not the whole site but rather only a container element on it.

Comment: Check the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview#position-strategies), `ConnectedPositionStrategy` should do what you want.

Comment: It's said to be deprecated tho. Is there some kind of newer / fresher way of handling these things?

Comment: I didn't see, you are right. Use `FlexibleConnectedPositionStrategy` as recommanded on the [Angular's Github](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/cdk/overlay/position/connected-position-strategy.ts)

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution, thanks to youri.

````js
private _getPositionStrategy() {
   let container = document.getElementById("container")
   return this.overlay
        .position()
        .flexibleConnectedTo(container)
        .withPush(false)
        .withPositions([{
          originX: 'center',
          originY: 'top',
          overlayX: 'center',
          overlayY: 'top',
        }])
     }```
````